# smbmount returns "operation not permitted"

Tags: 10.04, mount, samba

I use the smbfs tools package to mount my SMB shares. I wrote a quick script to mount the share:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/smbmount "\\\\somehost.local\\hostshare" /media/hostshare -o user=smbuser,dom=WORKGROUP,uid=localuser,gid=localgroup
```

This script used to work in 9.10 when called by the "localuser" account, but in my fresh-installed 10.04 it fails giving me the error:

```
mount error(1): Operation not permitted
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

The /media/hostshare directory is empty and has these perms:

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 localuser localgroup 4096 2010-12-12 12:04 hostshare/
```

The "localuser" is in these groups:

```
localgroup adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin admin sambashare
```

Any idea what is going on here? Google seems to suggest that the "sticky" bit needs to be set on `/sbin/mount.cifs` `/sbin/mount.smbfs` and `/sbin/umount.cifs`

Is this a bug?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this bug in Ubuntu:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/563805

and the related bug in Debian:

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=571323

This is an intentional change in behaviour for security reasons. Instead of using mount with the setuid bit set you might want to run it using sudo.

Comment: ah, ok, bummer for me!

Answer (score 1):

For me, adding the `sec=ntlmv2` parameter works.

Example:

```
sudo mount //server/share /localdirectory -o user=username,domain=WORKGROUP,sec=ntlmv2,iocharset=utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you previously customize the smb.conf?  If not, has the Windows system you're connecting to changed its configuration since the last time you connected?  One possible solution: Add the following in your **/etc/samba/smb.conf**

> client ntlmv2 auth = yes

Comment: Nope the windows box is unmodified, the only difference was the update to Ubuntu. I'll give the configuration change a test.